# Android ImageView should be larger than screen

Tags: android, imageview, transform, scale, dimensions

I have an Image that is 1500x2048

I want this to display at its native resolution, I will be handling zooming/scaling and transformation via android's animation functions.

Currently just using the ImageView by default it forces my image to fix within the screen size. I have tried expanding my XML elements to be `layout_width:"2048dip"` but to no success

How would this be done properly?

Comment: what would be a success? you can use scaleType or android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) attribute.